# Relative dropdown in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 4 drop downs. In the options I have written v-for. In my requirement I need to remove the option in the another three drop downs if an option selected in any of the other drop down. As well as vice versa if I change the option it should add on the other drop downs.

```
  <template>
  <div class="play">
    <div>
      <p>Select items you want to search in</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Destination 1</p>
      <select v-model="item1" name="palanet1" id="palanet1">
        <option value="-1">Select your item</option>
        <option v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:key="index">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <p>Destination 2</p>
      <select v-model="item2" name="palanet1" id="palanet1">
        <option value="-1">Select your item</option>
        <option v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:key="index">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <p>Destination 3</p>
      <select v-model="item3" name="palanet1" id="palanet1">
        <option value="-1">Select your item</option>
        <option v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:key="index">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
      <p>Destination 4</p>
      <select v-model="item4" name="palanet1" id="palanet1">
        <option value="-1">Select your item</option>
        <option v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:key="index">{{ item.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { name: "A", count: 1 },
        { name: "B", count: 2 },
        { name: "C", count: 3 },
        { name: "D", count: 4 },
        { name: "E", count: 5 },
        { name: "F", count: 6 }
      ],
      item1: -1,
      item2: -1,
      item3: -1,
      item4: -1
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

How can I do that using Vuejs?

Comment: you should have their own arrays of options for all there dropdown lists. And then you simply change these arrays.

Comment: Actually I receive the drop down options from an API. Then I'll make another three arrays and initialise the values.

Comment: Just use computed props as mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't be able to do it with Vue.js HTML directives if you're using the `<select>` and `<option>`, otherwise you'd be able to make a `div` within each item of the `v-for` that has a `v-if="item != item2 || item != item3 && item != item3"`

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

But Vue.js has computed properties!

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

I'd say make a different array each `v-for` displays with computed properties.

```
    // data stuff
    },
    computed: {
        list1() {
            return this.items.filter(item => {
                return ((item != this.item2 || this.item2 == -1) 
                       && (item != this.item3 || this.item2 == -1) 
                       && (item != this.item4 || this.item2 == -1));
            });
        }, 
        // ... and for the rest
    },
};
```

I think that will solve all your issues without having to keep separate arrays and bother with removing and re-adding items.

Comment: I am using axios in mounted so the computed is running before the value got filled.?

Comment: So what? They can return empty array if main array is also empty.

Comment: Filter will return an empty array if the array of items is empty as well, and v-for won't put anything in if the array is empty! So you should be safe.